# Calling Python UDF function for multiple files

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

How can we effectively call a Python UDF function for multiple CSV files in S3 stage? I have like ~450K CSV files (each in size of few KBs) coming in daily and I need to select only certain columns from each file and load it in table. I'm using a UDF to read the header and select only required columns. Right now it's taking ~10 mins to read and load the file. Is there any optimization technique available that can speed this process?

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the code for the UDF (as editable text)

Comment: https://medium.com/snowflake/loading-csv-as-semi-structured-files-in-snowflake-d7d76dfc37bf - same as here

Comment: All questions on this forum should be self-contained I.e contain all information necessary for someone to come up with an answer. Please don’t link to external sites